# Issue Management

Tags: project-management, system, management, content-management

I know this isn't about `programming` but i should learn "`Issue Management`"

What is `Issue Management`?

I read [Wikipedi page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_management) but i don't understand very well.

Can you tell me `Issue Management` and if there is some product for this subject?

Comment: Not sure if i understood what you are asking for but are you looking for the tool ? Check bug zlla then [http://www.bugzilla.org/](http://www.bugzilla.org/)

Comment: Issue Tracking = Bug/Task tracking. Try bugzilla.com or Atlassian JIRA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already answered what Issue Management is.

For commercial tools, many claim JIRA is the best. We've also had a good experience with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), which is free and open source.

Answer (score 3):

Issue Management as explained in the link you have given there in an development environment refers to the process of managing any problems / bugs / enhancements that have been logged against a system. These issues are logged by clients / users / testers / developers. The management of this process involves assigning resources to different issues, assigning estimated time, ensuring the retesting of the issues and planning the releases of the fixes.

There are so many issue tracking systems out there. Google PivotalTracker, FogzBugz - they are two examples of issue tracking systems.